# Positive Currency Values In WPF Telerik RadMaskTextBox Of Currency Mask

Tags: wpf, telerik, maskedtextbox

I am using a WPF Telerik RadMaskTextBox of Currency Mask in my application, but the problem is that I am able to enter negative currencies in this radmasktextbox. Is there a way, such that we can restrict the user to enter only positive values? If so, how?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get better answers if you ask this question in their forum . but anyway I was looking for the answer and I found a similar question however it's for their ASP controls but I think WPF should be the same .
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/input/numerictextbox-justinput-positive-integers.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanx for your comments. yes i have posted a question in their forum, and i am awaiting their reply. I checked out the link you have given, but i dont think its of much use in WPF RadMaskTextBox control, as there is no property called MinValue and hence, we are not able to restrict the value to positive values as such. also, i want the currency symbol ($) to appear. actually the control is working just fine, except for the fact that it accepts negative values, which is what i want to correct. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe Validation?**
One of the advantages to use elements from telerik is the easy way of **throwing validation exceptions** by wrong inputs from the user.
Also, if you have a save-method or whatever, you can prove if there are still exceptions from the user.

Here is a link that maybe helps you:
[Throwing Validation Exceptions](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmaskedinput/features/validation/validation) 
(There are many more validation tutorials for other elements)

**Or....**
But you can also just write this:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput maskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Minimum="0" />
```

(For more Infos: [Only Positive Inputs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmaskedinput/how-to/howto-enter-positive-values.html) )

Ps.: I know, just give you a bunch of links is not the best way, but I cound't explane it better than written on this pages.